# show that for $\phi \in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $(1+|x|)^{N} \phi(x)$ bounded

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

As the title suggests, I would like to show that for $\phi \in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $(1+|x|)^{N} \phi(x)$ bounded for some $N>n$, $$\overline{\mathscr{F}\phi(\xi)}= (2\pi)^{n}(\mathscr{F^{-1}\overline{\phi}})(\xi),$$ where the bar denotes complex conjugation.

I have recently learnt the basics of Fourier transform and as such I am still not very familiar with the proving type of questions. This is an optional question in my tutorial and I would be extremely grateful if someone could give me a hint or show me how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

The condition implies that $\phi\in L^{1}$ and hence the Fourier transform of $\phi$ makes sense, for the formula, one has 
\begin{align*}
\overline{\mathcal{F}\phi(\xi)}&=\overline{\int\phi(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}dx}\\
&=\int\overline{\phi(x)}e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}dx\\
&=\int\overline{\phi}(x)e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}dx\\
&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\overline{\phi}(\xi),
\end{align*}
the additional constant depends on the context.

Comment: thanks for your solution. May I ask how does one makes use of the given $(1+|x|)^{N} \phi (x)$ in the question? Would that lead to the constant $(2\pi )^{n}$ in this case?

Comment: I suspect the Fourier transform that you define is $e^{-ix\cdot\xi}$, after change of variable, there is a constant $(2\pi)^{n}$.

Comment: The condition is to prove that $\phi\in L^{1}$ by looking at the inequality that $|\phi(x)|\leq M/(1+|x|)^{N}$, and $\displaystyle\int 1/(1+|x|)^{N}<\infty$ by switching to polar coordinate.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. In my PDE course, the way we define is $e^{-ix. \xi}$ as you have mentioned. I apologise for not pointing it out clearly. Can you kindly elaborate regarding the change of variables? Thank you for your guidance thus far!

Comment: Sorry, actually that does not really have anything to do with change of variable. Rather, you may start to use the definition of your Fourier transform, do the conjugation like the way I did, and then the result will follow.

Comment: There must be some sort of $1/(2\pi)^{n}$ in front of your definition of the Fourier transform, so that does not really matter to the proof.

Comment: Noted! I will try it out again. Thanks once again!